# "for" vs. "fur"

Tags: pronunciation

[In a scene of Friends Season 2 Episode 1](https://youtu.be/X0lo9UybI7g?t=25), Phoebe helps Monica Cheats on Rachel and says

> went shopping **for fur**

Those two words sound the same.

According to Merriam-Webster, [fur](https://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/fur) is pronounced /ˈfɚ/, the weak form of [for](https://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/for) is /fɚ/.

So, in that scene, those two words do pronounce the same, is my understanding correct?

Comment: No, they are pronounced differently.

Answer (score 2):

They are very close, maybe identical, in sound, and the repetition of "for, um...for, um...for,um...for fur." is joking, using the similarity of the sounds to underline the woman's reluctance to admit that she was shopping for fur. She admits that shortly after, saying "And then I realized that I'm against that."

In some people's careful pronunciation, there is a difference, but in full-speed ordinary speech, they're about the same.

Comment: In typical speech, the vowel sound might be a bit longer in "fur". But the passage in the video is wordplay, so they are deliberately very similar.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on accent / dialect.   You will tend to hear the "weak form" of fur in a few places in the United States, and not elsewhere. (Asking if these are said the same way is one common question in an American accent key tree!)

On the other hand, usual pronunciation of "for" is with a full open o (/ɔ/) in both American and British English.   British speakers soften or elide the 'r' typically (when spoken before another consonant as is "for country", this sounds like "faw" to an American). But the vowel is never weak / rhotic.

So, to many Americans and probably most British speakers, "for" and "fur"  will *not* sound the same.  The clip you link is a joke about one of those accents in which they *are* the same - it would likely not be received as humorous if every American said these the same way.